# How can I repair a wrong, old merge commit in git?

Tags: git, merge

I have a feature branch named `feature`, which I merged to `staging`. There was a conflict, which I resolved. At that point, I made a mistake and introduced a syntax error that I committed with the merge commit. The error is in `staging`, but not in `feature`.

Afterwards, I made a few more subsequent commits to `feature` and merged those to `staging` without any conflicts. However, `staging` is broken because of the wrong merge commit. `feature` works, though.

Once development is done on `feature` and it works in `staging`, feature will be merged to a second staging level, and then to `master`.

All levels of staging as well as master have commit hooks on the remote that prevent any non-merge commits, so fixing it directly on `staging` is not going to work.

How do I repair the broken code in `staging`?

Comment: @Dan if I merge feature to staging again, it says it's already merged.

Comment: go to staging and repair it as hotfix

Comment: Here in the US I have not had enough coffee yet. Reading more carefully I see what you did. Your easiest option may be to fix it on `staging` directly, and then rebase `feature` if needed/appropriate (`git checkout feature; git rebase staging`) to avoid future trouble with merging.

Comment: Following @DanLowe is ok, but I cannt understand why are you adding a not completed fetaure to staging

Comment: @Dan we have a commit hook on our remote git that rejects everything that is not merge commits. I cannot make regular commits to that branch. Our workflow has another level of staging afterwards, so taking staging and rebasing it into feature might introduce other features that have been merged to staging, but have not yet been merged to the second staging level. If feature goes through the system faster, that will cause trouble later.

Comment: @F.bernal that's obvious: because the requirements changed :(

Comment: in that case you shouldn't reuse your old feature branch, you should create a new one from staging or development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As according to your comments on staging only merge commits are allowed, make a new branch from staging, fix the syntax error and then merge it back to staging.